# Get post content intro text on category.php?

Tags: categories, get-post

For some categories on my site there's introduction text that needs formatting (so using the category description isn't an option) and placing at the top of `categories.php`.

I've added a post ID to the category description field thinking I could then use `get_post()` to load the relevant post's content then list all the posts in the category underneath.

However it doesn't work and breaks the loop.

The error I get is

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /wp-content/themes/pap_01/loop.php on line 39

and line 39 is

```
$secintro = get_post(439);
print_r($secintro);
```

I've tried resetting post data and rewinding the loop after this but nothing helps. And `print_r($secintro);` does show anything either.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of WordPress. Upgrade to 3.5 and you will no longer see that error.

Here's the function declaration for `get_post` in WP 3.4:

```
function &get_post(&$post, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw')
```

Notice the ampersand in front of `$post`? That would mean the value is passed by reference. You can give the function a literal, it has to be the variable.

The correct solution is to update to WP 3.5 (we're on 3.5.1 at the time of writing). Get post to WP 3.5+:

```
function get_post( $post = null, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw' )
```

The less good way is to simply cheat when you call the function and do an assignment + call at the same time:

```
$a_post = get_post($a_post_id = 439);
```

`$a_post_id = 439` in the function arguments creates the `$a_post_id` variable and pass it into the function.

Answer (score 0):

used this in the end but still not sure why get_post wouldn't work

```
        $secintro_args =array(
            'post__in'=>array(439),
            'posts_per_page'=>1,
            'orderby'=>'title',
            'order'=>'asc');

        $secintro = get_posts($secintro_args);
```